# Saving the forms desktop location and size

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using winforms and I want to save the desktop location and size of the form when the user changes either. I found some useful code and put that in the form closing event and form load event to save and load the size and location respectively.

However, when the user directly shuts down the PC without closing the program first the changed size and location is not saved.

Therefore I used the same code in the size changed and location changed events but it does not work and size and location are not changed when the program restarts.

```
private void frmScopeStatus_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("WindowState", this.WindowState);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("WindowSizeH", this.Size.Height);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("WindowSizeW", this.Size.Width);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("LocationX", this.DesktopLocation.X);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("LocationY", this.DesktopLocation.Y);
}

 private void frmScopeStatus_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("WindowState", this.WindowState);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("WindowSizeH", this.Size.Height);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("WindowSizeW", this.Size.Width);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("LocationX", this.DesktopLocation.X);
    Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue("LocationY", this.DesktopLocation.Y);
}
```

Comment: For future reference: Please don't post walls of text with no commas, periods or paragraphs. Structure your text so it's easy to read.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide Application Settings data bindings of `User` scope to store these values.

- Open your form in designer
- Go to form properties `Data > (Application Settins)` group
- Add databining for `Location` (and `ClientSize`) property (scope User)
- On `FormClosing` event save changed properties `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

This will create for each user of your application file (at `%SYSTEMDRIVE%/Users/{username}/AppData/Local/CompanyName/AppName`) with user settings, which will be applied when application starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <AppName.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="FormLocation" serializeAs="String">
                <value>345, 234</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="FormSize" serializeAs="String">
                <value>458, 555</value>
            </setting>
        </AppName.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

*BTW* I think `FormClosed` event is better for saving application settings.

Comment: i was using form closing even before this but if the pc is directly shut down without closing the program first the code is not executed and hence the form size and location are not changed